# Why is Midoriya from My Hero Academia compared with Naruto and called "green Naruto"?

Tags: naruto, my-hero-academia

Many times in internet Midoriya from My Hero Academia is compared with Naruto and called "green Naruto". Why is this so? Is the character design? Is the style of My Hero Academia story compared with Naruto? Or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has to do with the concept of the Big 3. For a little bit of background on what the concept of the big 3 is you can take a look at [What phenomenon are at play such that the "Big Four" are limited to four and not a growing list?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/27187/what-phenomenon-are-at-play-such-that-the-big-four-are-limited-to-four-and-not).

With the ending of Naruto in sight at the time, and the great reception of Boku no Hero Academia (BNHA) at the same time, it became a sort of hand-off. People watching Naruto needed something new, and BNHA offered something similar but with a fresh twist, while it still kept true to the 'shonen' tropes everyone got so used to throughout the big 3 (and Dragon Ball).

This is similar to how the fandom created the picture of Goku handing over his 'success' to the logical new big 3 at the time. The fandom also created the hand-off from Naruto to BNHA, due to the exit of Naruto, and successful entry of BNHA.

As Midoriya thus is replacing Naruto in the mix of the big 3, he is often regarded as the green Naruto.

[image: Manga image where Naruto tells Midoryia: “Now it’s up to you”]

Comment: I'm curious, who is the one in the middle between Luffy and Naruto? Is it Ichigo from Bleach?

Comment: @threeFatCat yes

Answer (score 0):

I think this also has to be mentioned, about "My Hero Academia"'s author.

> Horikoshi's favorite manga series include Naruto, One Piece, Akira, Tekkonkinkreet, and Boys on the Run. In a farewell bid upon the conclusion of the former, Horikoshi referred to it as the greatest shonen manga ever, as Naruto made up his childhood and was one of the primary inspirations behind My Hero Academia

[Kohei Horikoshi](https://myheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Kohei_Horikoshi)